# File transfer upload fails to run (ionic 2)

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to use Transfer but apparently something is wrong and I can not figure out why.

I tried following the documentation (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/transfer/) but I cannot make it work!

I also searched many answers both here and in the ionic forum but nothing worked!

Here is what I have:

```
let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append( 'X-DeviceAPIKEY', DeviceAPIKEY);
    headers.append( 'X-DeviceACUID', AccountUID);

    var url = this.BaseAPIurl+"UploadController.ashx";
    // File for Upload
    var targetPath = "./57826randomName.jpg";

    // File name only
    var filename = "57826randomName.jpg";
    const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
      fileKey: "file",
      fileName: filename,
      chunkedMode: false,
      mimeType: "image/jpeg",
      headers:headers,
      params: {
        filename:filename,
        RUID: RUID,
        MUID: MUID
      }
    };

    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Uploading...'
    });

    this.loading.present();
    try {
      // Use the FileTransfer to upload the image

      fileTransfer.upload(targetPath, url, options).then(data => {
        this.loading.dismiss();
        this.presentToast('Image successfully uploaded.');
      }, err => {
        this.loading.dismiss();
        this.presentToast('Error while uploading file.');
      });
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.log("ERROR",err);
    }
```

When I run this on the browser it seems like it never runs. The loading element is never dismissed. The static path here is for my PC. When I run it on the device I change the path. On the device it seems to run but returns with `Error while uploading file.`

Why would this happen? Can it be because of the path?

How should I use this plugin?

Thank you very much!

Comment: _I run this on the browser_.. it doesnt work with ionic serve.. use device/emulator

Comment: It still fails on the device. It runs but still fails.. Do you know why it would return error? Wrong path of the image? Thx

Comment: your file path will be the device path check http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/